C++ Multiple Inheritance: Implementing interfaces with overlapping virtual functions
I'm trying to design a class hierarchy in C++ where I have a base interface FooInterface with a pure virtual function foo(), and another interface FooBarInterface that should extend FooInterface and add an additional function bar(). I then have a class Foo that implements foo() from FooInterface, and a class FooBar that inherits from Foo and FooBarInterface and implements bar().
My goal is to have the func function accept a std::shared_ptr to any object that implements both foo() and bar().
#include <memory>

class FooInterface {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class FooBarInterface : public FooInterface {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class Foo : public FooInterface {
public:
    void foo() override {};
};

class FooBar : public Foo, public FooBarInterface {
public:
    void bar() override {};
};

void func(std::shared_ptr<FooBarInterface> fb) {}

int main() {
    func(std::make_shared<FooBar>());
}

Note: omitting virtual destructor.
However, this code does not compile probably because that foo() in FooBarInterface is not overridden in FooBar, even though FooBar inherits from Foo, which implements foo().
How should I modify my code? Or do you have any design pattern that I should refer to?

See dupe: Do ALL virtual functions need to be implemented in derived classes?

@user12002570 but why in this case FooBar does not get the implementation of foo from Foo ? (all 3 major compilers complain that FooBar is abstract - see demo). I didn't see an explanation in the dupe.

Reopened. Yes, the literal answer is in the question linked by @user12002570. But there's a more subtle issue that should be addressed; if FooInterface was a virtual base of both Foo and FooBarInterface the code would be valid through dominance.

@PeteBecker I actually noticed that while I was "playing" with the example. But why is FooBar abstract as is (without virtual inheritance) ? Why does it not inherit foo from Foo ?

@wohlstad -- in the code in the question there are two different FooInterface::foo functions, one coming through Foo and one coming through FooBarInterface. The second is not overridden, so FooBar is still abstract. When the FooInterface base is virtual FooInterface::foo overrides foo in both intermediate classes (and that's what "dominance" refers to).

@PeteBecker Now I get it. I missed the existance of 2 foos. Maybe you'd like to post an answer, because the proposed dupe does not address this issue as far as I could see.

Sigh. Please ignore the "dominance" link in my "Reopened" comment. The page it points at is nonsense.

I got lost in the Foos and the Bars and the Interfaces, so I'm going to rewrite the class hierarchy, keeping the same structure:
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

struct Intermediate1 : Base {
};

struct Intermediate2 : Base {
    void foo();
}

struct Derived : Intermediate1, Intermediate2 {
};

Derived d; // error: can't create object of an abstract type

An object of the Derived has two subobjects of type Base, one coming through Intermediate1 and the other coming through Intermediate2. So it has two different functions foo, one coming through Intermediate1 and one coming through Intermediate2. Since Intermediate1 does not override Base::foo (and Derived also doesn't override it), it's still a pure virtual function, so Derived is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
On the other hand (and how many folks picture inheritance of "interfaces" (quoted because C++ doesn't have a formal notion of an "interface")), a similar hierarchy could look like this:
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

struct Intermediate1 : virtual Base {
};

struct Intermediate2 : virtual Base {
    void foo();
}

struct Derived : Intermediate1, Intermediate2 {
};

Derived d; // okay, via "dominance"

Note the added virtual for the classes derived directly from Base. Now an object of type Derived has only one subobject of type Base, and the dominance rule says that in Derived, Intermediate2::foo overrides Base::foo, even though there is no override in Intermediate1. So Intermediate1 itself is an abstract class, but Derived is not, even though it doesn't override Base::foo; the override through Intermediate2 is sufficient.

Good explanation. +1. I would just add a note that the usage of the shared_ptr is not really relevant here, only the fact that FooBar is abstract (since the issue of using the ptr  was explicitly mentioned in the question).

Also, note that virtual inheritance is a design decision, not a coding decision. Don't make bases virtual just because it "solves" an overriding problem; make a base virtual because that's appropriate for the hierarchy you're designing. Bjarne's example: if you have a list Node class as a base (intrusive list), you'd write struct X : Node ... and struct Y : Node when you want to create a list of Xs and a list of Ys. If you have a derived class that's both an X and a Y you need two Node classes, not one, so you can use your list of Xs and your list of Ys.

If you want FooBar::foo to use Foo's implementation, you call it.
class FooBar : public Foo, public FooBarInterface {
public:
    void foo() override { Foo::foo(); } 
    void bar() override {};
};


The answer does not really explain why FooBar is abstract as is (without adding foo). See PeteBecker's answer for an explanation (it was missing from my answer as well, which is why I deleted it).
